# How to get RenderingMetadata in Deployer Exension?

Tags: web8, metadata, deployer-extension

I want to add Component's metadata to transport package, and get it from Deployer Extension.
I wrote following code in C# TBB, then metadata is included in `component_presentations.xml`, which is in Transport package, 
as `RenderingMetadata` element.

```
_engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddMetadata(component.Metadata);
```

But I cannot find how to get the `RenderingMetadata` from Deployer Extension.

Is there any API in Deployer Extension to get `RenderingMetadata`?

Or is writing code to get `RenderingMetadata` from `component_presentations.xml`  required?

I find this method in following page.

http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/10/rendereditem-metadata-and-instruction.html

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2013 in your deployer extension you could get this with the following syntax:

```
String renderAddedMeta = page.getRenderAddedMetaData();
```

This example is for a `PageDeploy`. You have access to the `page` object in the `processPage` method. Similarly you can do the same for component presentations.

I am unable to verify at the moment, but Web8 must have something similar.